# Are airside connections possible at EWR?

Tags: air-travel, connecting-flights, ewr

I am flying overseas next weekend via Newark Airport with a short layover. My incoming flight arrives at Terminal C and my outgoing flight leaves from Terminal B. I have tried to get information from United Airlines, but I haven't had any luck. Is the airside shuttle bus at Newark Airport running right now?

Comment: We don't know your airport of overseas departure. If you return to the US from an overseas airport that does not have a [US CBP Preclearance Facility](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/preclearance), then you'll have to pass US Immigration and Customs immediately upon arrival in Terminal C. In that case, you won't be able to get to any airside transit until you again pass through Security.

Comment: My route is from Florida to EWR then on to Europe. As I mentioned I have been unable to get current information from United Airlines as to whether or not their airside shuttle is operating. Thanks.

Comment: [This official EWR page](https://newarkairport.com/at-airport/connecting-flights) describes the airside, inter-terminal shuttles.

Comment: Thanks, yes it does explain everything but is the airside shuttle actually operating? There is a lot of available information on the internet but unfortunately not all is current.

Comment: There is a [Contacts](https://www.panynj.gov/port-authority/en/help-center/contact-us.html#airports) page with phone numbers for the airport. Have you called to ask?

Comment: Thanks for the contacts page info. I called several numbers and have never been able to talk to a person. Somehow I thought that someone who had recently travelled through Newark would respond to my query.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've no further suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

When I went through EWR in late December I think it was running (not 100% sure), which was not a case maybe 6 months ago. Please note the shuttle only runs in the afternoon.

If there is no shuttle, you need to take the Airtrain which means you will have to go through security in Terminal B again. Having TSAPre would certainly help with that.

If this is a single ticket the airline has responsibility for making the connection possible. They know quite well how long the average connection: if it's too risky they wouldn't have sold you a ticket. If you miss it, they will rebook you on the next available flight.

If these are two separate tickets you are out of luck.

Comment: note that the piers of Terminal B are not connected to each other airside, so depending on the exact flight and gate, an airside connection may not be possible even if some C to B connections are.

Comment: Fair, but if it's a single ticket (say United/Lufthansa) the shuttle is very likely to go to the right location. I took the shuttle once and was able to board an LH flight directly.

Comment: We have had questions [fairly recently](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/178286/connecting-at-ewr-from-terminal-c-ua-domestic-to-b-international-departure-sq) from people connecting to flights for which UA codeshares are available but which go from the "wrong" part of Terminal B, and without more information than "Europe" as regards the destination or operating carrier, we can not be certain.