# Connecting at EWR from Terminal C (UA domestic) to B (International departure SQ)

Tags: air-travel, transit, connecting-flights, ewr

I'm flying on UA, connecting at EWR to an outboard international flight on SQ.

1. I should be arriving at Terminal C/UA and transferring to Terminal B for international departure for SQ?
2. Is 2hr 30mins enough for transfer? This is on 2 tickets, however, both UA and SQ are on Star Alliance which I believe I can ask to "join" the ticket for a baggage check-thru at UA check in counter? I land 07:19 and the SQ flight is at 09:45
3. Does the air-side shuttle bus from Terminal C to B run in the morning? The Newark [website](https://www.newarkairport.com/at-airport/connecting-flights) seems to say it only runs in the afternoon?

> United Airlines Operates a shuttle bus between Terminals A and C from
> 5:00 am to 10:00 pm. In addition, United operates a one-way shuttle
> bus connecting Terminal A to Terminal B and Terminal C to Terminal B
> between the hours of 1:00 pm and 11:00 pm (i.e., customers in Terminal
> B cannot use the shuttle bus to go to Terminals A and C).

Thanks!

Comment: Even when the shuttle bus is running, it goes to gate B67, which is not accessible airside from gate B53 which Singapore Airlines uses at Newark, so there is really no chance of doing this connection without re-clearing security.

Answer (score 1):

For 3. the easiest is taking the monorail between terminals. From terminal C - B it is 2-3 minutes and this train runs every 5 minutes i think. here is the link to the [airtrain map](https://www.newarkairport.com/static/ewr/pdf/ewr-airtrain-brochure-english.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

> Is 2hr 30mins enough for transfer?

I don't think so. This feels very risky, especially given the consequences of missing an ultra long haul flight.

> I believe I can ask to "join" the ticket for a baggage check-thru at UA check in counter?

I'm not sure if that's possible. Life would be a lot easier if this can be "joined" into a single ticket but this may trigger a change fee and re-pricing at the new ticket price.

> Does the air-side shuttle bus from Terminal C to B run in the morning?

Per current information from various websites the answer is "no". I found the bus availability to be dicey and website info not always be up to date.

Unless you can turn this into a single ticket (where the airline takes responsibility for a missed connection), I would not do this. It's quite likely that you have to collect your bags in Terminal C, take the train to terminal B, check the bags at the SQ check in counter and re-clear security. SQ check in closes one hour before departure.

My last few flights into EWR domestically where considerably delayed. It's hard to predict but this feels too risky to me. Consider flying in the night before and grabbing an airport hotel.